# Using tidyverse, sum values conditionally on distributions within each subset

Tags: r, normal-distribution, tidyverse, standard-deviation

I have an example dataframe below where each day of the `month` and `precip`  are recorded.

```
set.seed(560)
 df<-data.frame(month= rep(1:4, each=30), 
           precip= rep(c(rnorm(30, 20, 10), rnorm(30, 10, 2), 
           rnorm(30, 50, 1), rnorm(30, 15, 3))))
```

For each subset, I wish to count the number of instances a value was +/- 2 standard deviations (sd) above or below the mean of that month's `precip` values. Essentially I ned to find values at the extremes of the distribution of values (i.e. the tails of the distribution). This result column will be called `count`.

The output would appear as follows for this example dataset:

```
set.seed(560)
output<-data.frame(month= rep(1:4, each=1), count= c(1,2,1,1))
```

Notice for month 1 values above 35.969 and values below 2.61 are within +/- 2sd of the mean.  One value (precip=41.1) fits this requirement. Proof:

```
sub1<- subset(df, month==1)
  v1<- mean(sub1$precip)+ 2*sd(sub1$precip)#35.969
  v2<- mean(sub1$precip)- 2*sd(sub1$precip)#2.61
sub2<- subset(df, month==2)
 v3<- mean(sub2$precip)+ 2*sd(sub2$precip)#13.89
 v4<- mean(sub2$precip)- 2*sd(sub2$precip)#7.35
sub3<- subset(df, month==3)
 v5<- mean(sub3$precip)+ 2*sd(sub3$precip)#51.83
 v6<- mean(sub3$precip)- 2*sd(sub3$precip)#48.308
sub4<- subset(df, month==4)
 v7<- mean(sub4$precip)+ 2*sd(sub4$precip)#18.69
 v8<- mean(sub4$precip)- 2*sd(sub4$precip)#9.39
```

I have tried:

```
 output<- 
 df %>%
 group_by(month)%>%
 summarise(count= sum(precip > (mean(precip)+(2*sd(precip)))& 
                      precip < (mean(precip)-(2*sd(precip))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple fix, change your logic AND `&` to OR `|` as no row will be in both conditions.

```
output<- 
  df %>%
  group_by(month)%>%
  summarise(count= sum(precip > (mean(precip)+(2*sd(precip))) | 
                       precip < (mean(precip)-(2*sd(precip)))))

output
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   month count
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     2
# 4     4     1
```

And to add a base R solution using `by` (the counterpart to `dplyr::group_by()`)

```
do.call(rbind, 
        by(df, df$month, FUN=function(i){
           tmp <- i[i$precip < mean(i$precip) - 2*sd(i$precip) |
                    i$precip > mean(i$precip) + 2*sd(i$precip),]

           return(data.frame(month=i$month[[1]], count=nrow(tmp)))
           })
        )

#   month count
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     2
# 4     4     1
```

Alternatively, with `ave`, `ifelse`, and `aggregate`:

```
df$count <- ifelse(df$precip > ave(df$precip, df$month, FUN=function(g) mean(g) + 2*sd(g)) | 
                   df$precip < ave(df$precip, df$month, FUN=function(g) mean(g) - 2*sd(g)), 1, 0)

aggregate(count ~ month, df, FUN=sum)

#   month count
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     2
# 4     4     1
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```
tapply(df$precip, df$month, function(a) sum(abs(scale(a)) >= 2))
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 2 1
```